# Split textual script into substrings by pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, string-parsing

Consider following script (it's total nonsense in pseudo-language):

```
if (Request.hostMatch("asfasfasf.com") && someString.existsIn(new String[] {"brr", "hrr"}))   {
    if (Requqest.clientIp("10.0.x.x")) {
        somevar = "1";
    }
    somevar = "2";
}
else {
    somevar = "first";
}
string foo = "foo";
// etc. etc.
```

How would you grab if-block's parameters and contents from it? The if-block has format of:

```
if<whitespace>(<parameters>)<whitespace>{<contents>}<anything>
```

I tried using `String.split()` with regex pattern of `^if\s*\(|\)\s*\{|\}\s*` but this fails miserably. Namely, the problem is that `) {` is found also in inner if-block and the closing `}` is found from many places as well. I don't think neither lazy or eager expansion works here.

So... any pointers to what might I need here in order to implement this with regex?

I also need to get the remaining string without the if-block's code (so code starting from `else { ...`). Using just `String.split()` seems to make it difficult as there is no information about the length of the parts that were parsed away.

I initially created a loop based solution (using `String.substring()` heavily) for this, but it's dull. I would like to have something fancier instead. Should I go with regex or create a custom, generic function (there are many other cases than just this) that takes the parseable String and the pattern instead (consider the `if<whitespace>(...` pattern above)?

**Edit**: Changed returns to variable assignments as it would have not made sense otherwise.

Comment: As a non-regular language, this cannot be parsed by regex. You'll have to use a parser if you want this done in a reliable fashion.

Comment: Care to elaborate what you mean by non-regular language? The language does have a strict structure, it is very bash-like but there are special cases, yes. However, it is all "structured".

Comment: Ok, non-regular language stuff is explained/linked in Trey's answer. Check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular language won't work because a [regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) can't match things like "any number of open parenthesis followed by any number of close parenthesis".  A [context-free grammar](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/grammars/cfg.html) would be needed for that.

Unless you use a [context-free grammar parser for Java](http://beaver.sourceforge.net/index.html) or a regular expression extension that [makes regular expressions no longer regular](http://www.truerwords.net/5711), your loop-based solution is probably the fanciest solution.

Comment: Wow, this just got way more technical than I was excepting. I clearly have things to study here. Anyway, I guess this is the resolution then, thanks for the explanation and links!

Comment: For more information on this field look up formal language and automata theory.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be far better off using (or writing) a parser than trying to do this with Regex.

Regex is great for somethings, but for complex parsing like this, it sucks. Another example where it sucks that gets asked a lot here is parsing HTML - you can do it to a limited degree, but for anything complex, a DOM parser is a much better solution.

For a [very] simple parser, what you need is a recursive function that searches for a braces `{` and `}`, recursing down a level each time it comes across an opening brace, and returning back up a level when it finds a closing brace. It then needs to store the string contents between the two braces at each level.

Comment: Nice to hear such honest opinions and suggestions. My current implementation doesn't use recursion but I agree that would actually be a better solution. Thanks for your input, unfortunately I'm picking Trey's answer as accepted, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the above, you'll need a parser.  One type that's easy to implement (and fun to write!) is a [recursive descent parser with backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). There is also a plethora of parser generators out there, though most of those have a learning curve.  One Java-friendly parser generator is [JavaCC](https://javacc.dev.java.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. JavaCC documentation looks at lot more complete compared to that of Beaver's. However, both have learning curve as you say, so I'm probably going with a custom implementation. Reading about parsers I find out that my current implementation is actually pretty similar :)

Comment: I've never used a parser generator.  On the rare occasion I have needed one, it was simple enough to code by hand.